# splitting a string based on multiple char delimiters

Tags: c#, .net, string, split

I have a string "4,6,8\n9,4"

I want to split this based on ,and \n

Output array should be

```
4
6
8
9
4
```

**Edit :**

Now i am reading string from console , when i enter a string as above in console , in the code behind i get as `"4,6,8\\n9,4"` . Now that i want to split using `"," and "\\n"` . How can i change the expression ?

Answer (score 163, accepted):

Use [string.Split(char [])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx)

```
string strings = "4,6,8\n9,4";
string [] split = strings .Split(new Char [] {',' , '\n' });
```

**EDIT**

Try following if you get any unnecessary empty items. [String.Split Method (String[], StringSplitOptions)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx)

```
string [] split = strings .Split(new Char [] {',' , '\n' }, 
                                 StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

**EDIT2**

This works for your updated question. Add all the necessary split characters to the `char []`.

```
string [] split = strings.Split(new Char[] { ',', '\\', '\n' },
                                 StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: I could not get this to work using `.Split(new Char[]{'?='})`, but doing this helped http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126915/how-do-i-split-a-string-by-a-multi-character-delimiter-in-c. Great answer none the less

Comment: @CSharper You're doing it wrong. You should do `.Split(new Char[]{'?','='})`

Comment: Is there a way to know which character in the array was used to split the string? (assuming you need to know this value?)

Comment: @RobertGreenMBA No standard method. You can use split method for each character. Create your own method for your requirement.

Comment: ReSharper will recommend this format: `new[] { ',', '\\', '\n' }`

Answer (score 12):

Another option is to use [Regex.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byy2946e.aspx). This is useful when the split sequences are more complex. For instance if spaces can also be part of the split delimiters such as:

```
"4,6,8 , 9\\n\\n4"
```

Then:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
var i = "4,6,8 , 9\n\n4";
var o = Regex.Split(i, @"[,\s\n]+");
// now o is:
// new string[] { "4", "6", "8", "9" }
```

Note that the regular expression used is "more accepting" - it ignored the empty "space" between the \n's and it would accept "4 6 8 9 4" just the same - so the above to to show a point: there is more than one way to skin a cat.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 7):

```
var s = "4,6,8\n9,4";
var split = s.Split(new char[]{',', '\n'});
```

But this has to be a dupe...

**EDIT**:  Addressing the comment.

This code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var s = "4,6,8\n9,4";

    foreach (var a in s.Split(new char[] { ',', '\n' }))
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(a);
}
```

Outputs this:

```
4
6
8
9
4
```

**EDIT**:  Reading input from the console is different.  `\n` is different when entered manually.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var s = "4,6,8\\n9,4";

    foreach (var a in s.Split(new string[] { ",", "\\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(a);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
string tosplit = "4,6,8\n9,4";
var split = tosplit.Split(new Char [] {',', '\n' });
```

Just in case you are not printing / seeing it properly:

```
split.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Comment: @Nithesh Hebri - It gives the correct output that you want, for me.

Answer (score 2):

Can you do a string.Replace('\n',',') followed by the string.split(',') ?

Answer (score 0):

```
// input string
string input = "email@domain.com;email2@domain.com,email3@domain.com;";

// each character in this string will split it
string splitBy = ",;";

// do the split, remove any blank results
string[] result = input.Split(splitBy.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

output is an array of strings:

```
email@domain.com
email2@domain.com
email3@domain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

for every cases

```
    string s = "";
    s.Split(new string[] { ",", "DEL", ";"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```