# String.Split() with default(string[]) as delimiter, how does it work?

Tags: c#

In some C# code I saw `default(string[])` is `null`, but the behavior looks like it is splitting based on whitespace:

```
string[] x = "1 2   3".Split(default(string[]), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string[] y = "1,2,  3".Split(default(string[]), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Here, `x` becomes `string[3] = {"1","2","3"}`, `y` becomes `string[2] = {"1,2,","3"}`.

My input string can be separated using whitespace or comma i.e."1 2   3" OR "1,2,  3". But i want output to be numeric array string i.e. {"1","2","3"}

How can I achieve this?

Comment: use a regex to split the string instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [splitting a string based on multiple char delimiters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605785/splitting-a-string-based-on-multiple-char-delimiters)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not particularly useful nor readable to use `default(string[])` as an argument, because that can (and will by the compiler) be simplified to merely `null`, which is way more readable.

Then you'll go and [read the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If the separator parameter is null or contains no characters, white-space characters are assumed to be the delimiters. White-space characters are defined by the Unicode standard and return true if they are passed to the Char.IsWhiteSpace method.

If you want to split on multiple delimiters, then try searching for that: [splitting a string based on multiple char delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605785/splitting-a-string-based-on-multiple-char-delimiters)

Comment: @sahil: nobody has said that existing code must make sense or be useful. Existing code can be crap.

Comment: Agreed. Makes sense. I didn't know about this conversion so wanted to confirm it.

Answer (score 0):

Use another override of Split with char array instead

```
Split(new []{',',' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```