# Format LookUp values, retrieved from WebServices

Tags: c#, linq, web-services, sharepoint

I am working with Lists WebService and on retrieval of XML data, I need to format it in a nice and clean format to be displayed on front-end. I am getting values of loopup as below format

```
12;#Infor ERP Baan;#15;#Infor ERP LN;#31;#Infor PM;#32;#Infor SCM
```

and I need to display it as a bullet list, and for I'll need the values to be just separated by ";" to that I can putt in for loop and add `<li>`, something like

```
 Infor ERP Baan;Infor ERP LN;Infor PM;Infor SCM
```

Answer (score 2):

I have used the following function and regular expression to split the data when returning lookup data from SharePoint.

```
    static private Dictionary<int,string> GetValues(string productsCellData)
    {
        // regular expression to split the data into an array, we need the ExplictCapture
        // to prevent c# capturing the ;#
        var regex = new Regex(@"((?<=\d);#|;#(?=\d))", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);

        // our array of data that has been processed.
        var productsCellsArray = regex.Split(productsCellData);

        Dictionary<int, string> productsDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        if (productsCellsArray.Length % 2 == 1)
        {
            // handle badly formatted string the array length should always be an even number.
        }

        // set local variables to hold the data in the loop.
        int productKey = -1;
        string productValue = string.Empty;

        // loop over the array and create our dictionary.
        for (var i = 0; i < productsCellsArray.Length; i++)
        {
            var item = productsCellsArray[i];
            // process odd/even
            switch (i % 2)
            { 
                case 0:
                    productKey = Int32.Parse(item);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    productValue = item;
                    if (productKey > 0)
                    {
                        productsDictionary.Add(productKey, productValue);
                        productKey = -1;
                        productValue = string.Empty;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        return productsDictionary;
    }
```

This has the advantage of processing the delimiter ;# if it appears (unlikely as it seems) in the value section.

It also has the following advantages

1. Lookup values from the Id
2. Get Array of Id's from the dictionary
3. Get Array of Values from the dictionary
4. Check if a value exists in the dictionary
5. Check if an id exists in the dictionary

Hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent answer. I had this need to and after a lot of research on where to do it (i.e. in T-SQL using `PATINDEX` and `REPLACE` or in C# using Regex, I settled on your method. Like you say, it is very flexible. I wrote a Console app to test out your code for various lookup string instances in my project and this works great! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

A lookup field value in SharePoint contains two pieces of information - an ID of the item being looked up and the textual value of the referenced field. These are combined together in one string using `;#` as a separator. 
What you have here, is a value of `SPFieldLookupMulti` - field where you can have multiple values selected at the moment. Hence, it contains ID1;#value1;#ID2;#value2...

The easiest solution is to `String.Split` up by `;#` substring (see this response to find out, how: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1126933/239599) then access only the even indices of the resulting array: 0th element contains ID1, 1st element contains value1; 2nd element contains ID2; 3rd element contains value2.

So you can use a `for` loop and increment the counter by 2.

Comment: string[] nProductsCellData = Regex.Replace(ProductsCellData, @"\d", ";").Replace(";#", "").Replace(";;", ";").Split(';');
                    foreach (string product in nProductsCellData)
                    {
                        if (product != "")
                        {
                            e.Row.Cells[i].Text += "<li>" + product + "</li>";
                        }
                    }

Answer (score -1):

The best way to do this would be :

```
ProductsCellData = "12;#Infor ERP Baan;#15;#Infor ERP LN;#31;#Infor PM;#32;#Infor SCM"

      string[] nProductsCellData = Regex.Replace(ProductsCellData, @"\d", ";").Replace(";#", "").Replace(";;", ";").Split(';');
                        foreach (string product in nProductsCellData)
                        {
                            if (product != "")
                            {
                                e.Row.Cells[i].Text += "<li>" + product + "</li>";
                            }
                        }
```