# Split string with pattern in C#

Tags: c#, string, split

I have a string in C# that look with pattern like this:

```
string Str = "!!DATA!!First!!Data!!Second!!DATA!!";
```

How can I split the string into array of string that contains that parts between the !!DATA!! parts?

Comment: Try [`String.Split()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx), or a [regular expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx). What did you try?

Comment: The following link should provide the guidance you need ...   
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126915/how-do-i-split-a-string-by-a-multi-character-delimiter-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you do any research?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx

```
string[] data = Str.Split( new string[]{"!!DATA!!"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries )
```

or maybe you want

```
string[] data = Str.Split( new string[]{"!!DATA!!","!!Data!!"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries );
```

Answer (score 4):

it seems that you want a case insensitive !!DATA!! pattern
the best solution for this is to use Regex

```
string[] data = Regex.Split(Str , "!!DATA!!",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string[] data = Str.Split(new string[] { "!!Data!!", "!!DATA!!" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] data = yourString.Split(new string[] {"!!DATA!!"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx) for further info.

Comment: This doesn't do what you might expect

Comment: @ohmusama Yeah you're right, I've checked MSDN, I thought there was an overload like this.

Comment: Its super annoying, you could always implement a extension method to do so, but that is out of the scope of this question.

Answer (score -2):

```
string[] newstring=Str.Split('!!Data!!');
```

Comment: '!!Data!!' it's not a char.