# Function for splitting by substring

Tags: c#

I have text

```
Hi, my name is <b>Dan</b> and i need/n to separate string
```

What I need is to find specific tags and separate text by predefined tags like /n or (b),
the result need to be:

```
Str[0] = Hi, my name is
Str[1] = Dan
Str[2] = and i need
Str[3] = to separate string
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: Did your have a look at Regex.Split? ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ze12yx1d(v=vs.110).aspx )

Comment: the String.Split accept an array of delimiter that you specify to split on. if you give it `new [] {"a","b"}` as the array delimiter the following `this blueberry is on the table` will give `[]{"this ","lue","erry is on the t","ble"}` splitting for any `a` or `b`

Comment: Do you mean "/n" or "\n"?

Comment: *Did you have a look at `Regex.Split`?*... clearly, this user didn't look at anything, or make any effort themselves before asking this question. -1

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I split a string by a multi-character delimiter in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126915/how-do-i-split-a-string-by-a-multi-character-delimiter-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
string[] separators = {"<b>", "</b>", "\\n"};
string value = "Hi, my name is <b>Dan</b> and i need \\n to separate string";
string[] words = value.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
const string source = "hi, my name is <b>Dan</b> and i need/n to separate string";
var res = Regex.Split(source, "(</?b>)|(/n)").Where(x => !Regex.IsMatch(x, "(</?b>)|(/n)")).ToArray();
```