# create array of integer from textbox

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I want to create an array of integer from textbox.

format string inside textbox is 80, 139, 22, 135, and more.

so far this is what I have.

> This is working if textbox is 80 or 139 or 22 or any without "," or space

```
Dim XPort = {TxtScanPort.Text}.ToList 
For Each BPort As Integer In XPort 'ERROR
Blahh.. blahh.. blahh..
```

but when I change value inside texbox to 80, 139, 135 then I get this error..

> Conversion from string "80, 139, 135" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

then I am trying to convert string to integer.. like this..

```
Dim XPort = {TxtScanPort.Text}.ToList
Dim Str2Int = XPort.ConvertAll(Function(str) Int32.Parse(str)) 'ERROR
For Each BPort As Integer In Str2Int
Blahh.. blahh.. blahh..
```

then I have another error..

> Input string was not in a correct format.

I have trying many code, but the most of them result same error "Input string was not in a correct format"

Comment: `"80, 139, 135"` is not an integer, it is a CSV.  Parse or split it first ...blahh blahh blahh

Comment: If you consider your comma and space (", ") as a multi-character delimiter, then [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126915/how-do-i-split-a-string-by-a-multi-character-delimiter-in-c) might be able to help you if you don't mind translating the C# code into VB.NET. (Alternatively, take a look at the [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) method.)

Comment: @ChristopherKyleHorton thanks its working..

Answer (score 1):

Not a fan of String.Split() (get a real CSV parser), but this is the quick'n'dirty option:

```
For Each BPort As Integer In TxtScanPort.Text.Split(",".ToCharArray()).Select(Function(i) CInt(i.Trim()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method that should work if each value is delimited by a comma.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim Values() As Integer = Array.ConvertAll(TxtScanPort.Text.Split(","c),
            New Converter(Of String, Integer)(Function(input)
                                                  Dim output As Integer = 0
                                                  Integer.TryParse(input, output)
                                                  Return output
                                              End Function))

        For Each BPort As Integer In Values
            Console.WriteLine(BPort)
        Next

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code is that of ArrayDemo.xaml:

```
'Declarations:Nested_Buttons
Dim WM As Window=New Window:Dim canvas1 As Canvas=New Canvas
Dim vb As Viewbox = New Viewbox()
Dim btn1 As Button=New Button:Dim btn2 As Button=New Button

Dim Editor As TextBox=New TextBox
Dim ay0 As TextBox = New TextBox:Dim ay1 As TextBox = New TextBox
Dim ay2 As TextBox = New TextBox:Dim ay3 As TextBox = New TextBox
Dim ay4 As TextBox = New TextBox:Dim ay5 As TextBox = New TextBox
Dim ay6 As TextBox = New TextBox:Dim ay7 As TextBox = New TextBox
Dim ay8 As TextBox = New TextBox:Dim ay9 As TextBox = New TextBox
Dim ay10 As TextBox = New TextBox:Dim ay11 As TextBox = New TextBox
Dim ay12 As TextBox = New TextBox:Dim ay13 As TextBox = New TextBox
Dim ay14 As TextBox = New TextBox:Dim ay15 As TextBox = New TextBox
Dim ay16 As TextBox = New TextBox:Dim ay17 As TextBox = New TextBox
Dim ay18 As TextBox = New TextBox:Dim ay19 As TextBox = New TextBox
Dim ay20 As TextBox = New TextBox:Dim ay21 As TextBox = New TextBox
Dim ay22 As TextBox = New TextBox:Dim ay23 As TextBox = New TextBox
Dim ay24 As TextBox = New TextBox:Dim ay25 As TextBox = New TextBox
Dim ay26 As TextBox = New TextBox:Dim ay27 As TextBox = New TextBox
Dim ay28 As TextBox = New TextBox:Dim ay29 As TextBox = New TextBox
Dim ay30 As TextBox = New TextBox:Dim ay31 As TextBox = New TextBox

Dim i As Integer=Nothing:Dim j As Integer=Nothing:Dim k As Integer=Nothing

Dim gradientBrush3 As New LinearGradientBrush(Color.FromRgb(175,238,238),Color.FromRgb(255,255,0), _
New Point(0.5, 0),New Point(0.5, 1))

Sub New()

WM.Width=1900:WM.Height=1040:WM.Background=Brushes.MediumSlateBlue:WM.Content=vb:WM.Left=0:WM.Top=0
WM.Title="ArrayDemo":vb.Child=canvas1:canvas1.Width=1875:canvas1.Height=960
vb.Width=1600:vb.Height=950

btn1.Width=150:btn1.Height=60:btn1.Margin=New Thickness(0,0,0,0)
btn1.Background=New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Brown)
btn1.FontSize=20:btn1.Foreground=New SolidColorBrush(Colors.White)
btn1.HorizontalAlignment=System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left
btn1.Content = New TextBlock With {.Text = "ArrayDemo", _ 
.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap}
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''Array TextBoxes         
ay0.Width=30:ay0.Height=43:ay0.Foreground=New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)
ay0.Background=gradientBrush3:ay0.FontSize=23
ay0.FontWeight=FontWeights.UltraBold:ay0.Text="0"
ay0.Margin=New Thickness(152,0,0,0)

ay1.Width=30:ay1.Height=43:ay1.Foreground=New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)
ay1.Background=gradientBrush3:ay1.FontSize=23
ay1.FontWeight=FontWeights.UltraBold:ay1.Text="1"
ay1.Margin=New Thickness(184,0,0,0)

ay2.Width=30:ay2.Height=43:ay2.Foreground=New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)
ay2.Background=gradientBrush3:ay2.FontSize=23
ay2.FontWeight=FontWeights.UltraBold:ay2.Text="1"
ay2.Margin=New Thickness(216,0,0,0)

ay3.Width=30:ay3.Height=43:ay3.Foreground=New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)
ay3.Background=gradientBrush3:ay3.FontSize=23
ay3.FontWeight=FontWeights.UltraBold:ay3.Text="3"
ay3.Margin=New Thickness(248,0,0,0)

ay4.Width=30:ay4.Height=43:ay4.Foreground=New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)
ay4.Background=gradientBrush3:ay4.FontSize=23
ay4.FontWeight=FontWeights.UltraBold:ay4.Text="1"
ay4.Margin=New Thickness(280,0,0,0)

ay5.Width=30:ay5.Height=43:ay5.Foreground=New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)
ay5.Background=gradientBrush3:ay5.FontSize=23
ay5.FontWeight=FontWeights.UltraBold:ay5.Text="1"
ay5.Margin=New Thickness(312,0,0,0)

ay6.Width=30:ay6.Height=43:ay6.Foreground=New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)
ay6.Background=gradientBrush3:ay6.FontSize=23
ay6.FontWeight=FontWeights.UltraBold:ay6.Text="21"
ay6.Margin=New Thickness(344,0,0,0)

ay7.Width=30:ay7.Height=43:ay7.Foreground=New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)
ay7.Background=gradientBrush3:ay7.FontSize=23
ay7.FontWeight=FontWeights.UltraBold:ay7.Text="9"
ay7.Margin=New Thickness(376,0,0,0)

ay8.Width=30:ay8.Height=43:ay8.Foreground=New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)
ay8.Background=gradientBrush3:ay8.FontSize=23
ay8.FontWeight=FontWeights.UltraBold:ay8.Text="9"
ay8.Margin=New Thickness(408,0,0,0)

ay9.Width=30:ay9.Height=43:ay9.Foreground=New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)
ay9.Background=gradientBrush3:ay9.FontSize=23
ay9.FontWeight=FontWeights.UltraBold:ay9.Text="1"
ay9.Margin=New Thickness(440,0,0,0)

ay10.Width=30:ay10.Height=43:ay10.Foreground=New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)
ay10.Background=gradientBrush3:ay10.FontSize=23
ay10.FontWeight=FontWeights.UltraBold:ay10.Text="3"
ay10.Margin=New Thickness(472,0,0,0)

ay11.Width=30:ay11.Height=43:ay11.Foreground=New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)
ay11.Background=gradientBrush3:ay11.FontSize=23
ay11.FontWeight=FontWeights.UltraBold:ay11.Text="3"
ay11.Margin=New Thickness(504,0,0,0)

ay12.Width=30:ay12.Height=43:ay12.Foreground=New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)
ay12.Background=gradientBrush3:ay12.FontSize=23
ay12.FontWeight=FontWeights.UltraBold:ay12.Text="3"
ay12.Margin=New Thickness(536,0,0,0)

ay13.Width=30:ay13.Height=43:ay13.Foreground=New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)
ay13.Background=gradientBrush3:ay13.FontSize=23
ay13.FontWeight=FontWeights.UltraBold:ay13.Text="1"
ay13.Margin=New Thickness(568,0,0,0)

ay14.Width=30:ay14.Height=43:ay14.Foreground=New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)
ay14.Background=gradientBrush3:ay14.FontSize=23
ay14.FontWeight=FontWeights.UltraBold:ay14.Text="5"
ay14.Margin=New Thickness(600,0,0,0)

ay15.Width=30:ay15.Height=43:ay15.Foreground=New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)
ay15.Background=gradientBrush3:ay15.FontSize=23
ay15.FontWeight=FontWeights.UltraBold:ay15.Text="5"
ay15.Margin=New Thickness(632,0,0,0)

ay16.Width=30:ay16.Height=43:ay16.Foreground=New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)
ay16.Background=gradientBrush3:ay16.FontSize=23
ay16.FontWeight=FontWeights.UltraBold:ay16.Text="31"
ay16.Margin=New Thickness(664,0,0,0)

ay17.Width=30:ay17.Height=43:ay17.Foreground=New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)
ay17.Background=gradientBrush3:ay17.FontSize=23
ay17.FontWeight=FontWeights.UltraBold:ay17.Text="11"
ay17.Margin=New Thickness(696,0,0,0)

ay18.Width=30:ay18.Height=43:ay18.Foreground=New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)
ay18.Background=gradientBrush3:ay18.FontSize=23
ay18.FontWeight=FontWeights.UltraBold:ay18.Text="9"
ay18.Margin=New Thickness(728,0,0,0)

ay19.Width=30:ay19.Height=43:ay19.Foreground=New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)
ay19.Background=gradientBrush3:ay19.FontSize=23
ay19.FontWeight=FontWeights.UltraBold:ay19.Text="1"
ay19.Margin=New Thickness(760,0,0,0)

ay20.Width=30:ay20.Height=43:ay20.Foreground=New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)
ay20.Background=gradientBrush3:ay20.FontSize=23
ay20.FontWeight=FontWeights.UltraBold:ay20.Text="3"
ay20.Margin=New Thickness(792,0,0,0)

ay21.Width=30:ay21.Height=43:ay21.Foreground=New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)
ay21.Background=gradientBrush3:ay21.FontSize=23
ay21.FontWeight=FontWeights.UltraBold:ay21.Text="1"
ay21.Margin=New Thickness(824,0,0,0)

ay22.Width=30:ay22.Height=43:ay22.Foreground=New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)
ay22.Background=gradientBrush3:ay22.FontSize=23
ay22.FontWeight=FontWeights.UltraBold:ay22.Text="3"
ay22.Margin=New Thickness(856,0,0,0)

ay23.Width=30:ay23.Height=43:ay23.Foreground=New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)
ay23.Background=gradientBrush3:ay23.FontSize=23
ay23.FontWeight=FontWeights.UltraBold:ay23.Text="7"
ay23.Margin=New Thickness(888,0,0,0)

ay24.Width=30:ay24.Height=43:ay24.Foreground=New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)
ay24.Background=gradientBrush3:ay24.FontSize=23
ay24.FontWeight=FontWeights.UltraBold:ay24.Text="51"
ay24.Margin=New Thickness(920,0,0,0)

ay25.Width=30:ay25.Height=43:ay25.Foreground=New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)
ay25.Background=gradientBrush3:ay25.FontSize=23
ay25.FontWeight=FontWeights.UltraBold:ay25.Text="5"
ay25.Margin=New Thickness(952,0,0,0)

ay26.Width=30:ay26.Height=43:ay26.Foreground=New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)
ay26.Background=gradientBrush3:ay26.FontSize=23
ay26.FontWeight=FontWeights.UltraBold:ay26.Text="1"
ay26.Margin=New Thickness(984,0,0,0)

ay27.Width=30:ay27.Height=43:ay27.Foreground=New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)
ay27.Background=gradientBrush3:ay27.FontSize=23
ay27.FontWeight=FontWeights.UltraBold:ay27.Text="1"
ay27.Margin=New Thickness(1016,0,0,0)

ay28.Width=30:ay28.Height=43:ay28.Foreground=New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)
ay28.Background=gradientBrush3:ay28.FontSize=23
ay28.FontWeight=FontWeights.UltraBold:ay28.Text="1"
ay28.Margin=New Thickness(1048,0,0,0)

ay29.Width=30:ay29.Height=43:ay29.Foreground=New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)
ay29.Background=gradientBrush3:ay29.FontSize=23
ay29.FontWeight=FontWeights.UltraBold:ay29.Text="1"
ay29.Margin=New Thickness(1080,0,0,0)

ay30.Width=30:ay30.Height=43:ay30.Foreground=New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)
ay30.Background=gradientBrush3:ay30.FontSize=23
ay30.FontWeight=FontWeights.UltraBold:ay30.Text="1"
ay30.Margin=New Thickness(1112,0,0,0)
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''Array TextBoxes
Editor.TextWrapping=TextWrapping.Wrap:Editor.AcceptsReturn = True
Editor.Width=1840:Editor.Height=900:Editor.Margin=New Thickness(0,62,0,0)
Editor.Background=New SolidColorBrush(Colors.White)
Editor.Foreground=New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Navy)
Editor.FontSize=22:Editor.FontWeight=FontWeights.UltraBold
Editor.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility=ScrollBarVisibility.Visible
Editor.VerticalScrollBarVisibility=ScrollBarVisibility.Visible
Editor.HorizontalContentAlignment=HorizontalAlignment.Left

canvas1.Children.Add(btn1):canvas1.Children.Add(Editor)

canvas1.Children.Add(ay0):canvas1.Children.Add(ay1):canvas1.Children.Add(ay2)
canvas1.Children.Add(ay3):canvas1.Children.Add(ay4):canvas1.Children.Add(ay5)
canvas1.Children.Add(ay6):canvas1.Children.Add(ay7):canvas1.Children.Add(ay8)
canvas1.Children.Add(ay9):canvas1.Children.Add(ay10):canvas1.Children.Add(ay11)
canvas1.Children.Add(ay12):canvas1.Children.Add(ay13):canvas1.Children.Add(ay14)
canvas1.Children.Add(ay15):canvas1.Children.Add(ay16):canvas1.Children.Add(ay17)
canvas1.Children.Add(ay18):canvas1.Children.Add(ay19):canvas1.Children.Add(ay20)
canvas1.Children.Add(ay21):canvas1.Children.Add(ay22):canvas1.Children.Add(ay23)
canvas1.Children.Add(ay24):canvas1.Children.Add(ay25):canvas1.Children.Add(ay26)
canvas1.Children.Add(ay27):canvas1.Children.Add(ay28):canvas1.Children.Add(ay29)
canvas1.Children.Add(ay30)

AddHandler btn1.Click,AddressOf btn1Handler

WM.Show()

End Sub 

Public Sub btn1Handler(sender As Object,e As EventArgs)
Try 
     Dim arr1() As Integer = {Integer.Parse(ay0.Text),Integer.Parse(ay1.Text),Integer.Parse(ay2.Text),Integer.Parse(ay3.Text), _
                                             Integer.Parse(ay4.Text),Integer.Parse(ay5.Text),Integer.Parse(ay6.Text),Integer.Parse(ay7.Text), _
                                             Integer.Parse(ay8.Text),Integer.Parse(ay9.Text),Integer.Parse(ay10.Text),Integer.Parse(ay11.Text), _
                                             Integer.Parse(ay12.Text),Integer.Parse(ay13.Text),Integer.Parse(ay14.Text),Integer.Parse(ay15.Text), _
                                             Integer.Parse(ay16.Text),Integer.Parse(ay17.Text),Integer.Parse(ay18.Text),Integer.Parse(ay19.Text), _
                                             Integer.Parse(ay20.Text),Integer.Parse(ay21.Text),Integer.Parse(ay22.Text),Integer.Parse(ay23.Text), _
                                             Integer.Parse(ay24.Text),Integer.Parse(ay25.Text),Integer.Parse(ay26.Text),Integer.Parse(ay27.Text), _
                                             Integer.Parse(ay28.Text),Integer.Parse(ay29.Text),Integer.Parse(ay30.Text)}
     Dim sName As Hashtable = New Hashtable 
     sName.Add(1,"pwBox"):sName.Add(2,"vwBox"):sName.Add(3,"canvas"):sName.Add(4,"tlbrTray"):
     sName.Add(5,"menuStrip"):sName.Add(6,"menu"):sName.Add(7,"sbMenu"):sName.Add(8,"mnMenu")
     sName.Add(9,"tlTip"):sName.Add(10,"grpBox"):sName.Add(11,"wrpPanel"):sName.Add(12,"dckPanel")
     sName.Add(13,"ufrmGrid"):sName.Add(14,"expr"):sName.Add(15,"border"):sName.Add(16,"btn")
     sName.Add(17,"label"):sName.Add(18,"tbx"):sName.Add(19,"Editor"):sName.Add(20,"listBox")
     sName.Add(21,"rtxBox"):sName.Add(22,"cboBox"):sName.Add(23,"chkBox"):sName.Add(24,"rdoBtn")
     sName.Add(25,"tglBtn"):sName.Add(26,"prgsBar"):sName.Add(27,"slider"):sName.Add(28,"scrlBar")
     sName.Add(29,"cusContrl1"):sName.Add(30,"cusContrl2")

     Dim ctrlName As Hashtable = New Hashtable
     ctrlName.Add(1,"PasswordBox"):ctrlName.Add(2,"ViewBox"):ctrlName.Add(3,"Canvas"):ctrlName.Add(4,"ToolBarTray")
     ctrlName.Add(5,"Menu"):ctrlName.Add(6,"MenuItem"):ctrlName.Add(7,"MenuItem"):ctrlName.Add(8,"MenuItem")
     ctrlName.Add(9,"ToolTip"):ctrlName.Add(10,"GroupBox"):ctrlName.Add(11,"wrapPanel"):ctrlName.Add(12,"DockPanel")
     ctrlName.Add(13,"UniformGrid"):ctrlName.Add(14,"Expander"):ctrlName.Add(15,"Border"):ctrlName.Add(16,"Button")
     ctrlName.Add(17,"Label"):ctrlName.Add(18,"TextBox"):ctrlName.Add(19,"TextBox"):ctrlName.Add(20,"ListBox")
     ctrlName.Add(21,"RichTextBox"):ctrlName.Add(22,"ComboBox"):ctrlName.Add(23,"CheckBox"):ctrlName.Add(24,"RadioButton")
     ctrlName.Add(25,"ToggleButton"):ctrlName.Add(26,"ProgressBar"):ctrlName.Add(27,"Slider"):ctrlName.Add(28,"ScrollBar")
     ctrlName.Add(29,"CustomControl"):ctrlName.Add(30,"CustomControl")
    Try           
         For j=1 To 30 Step 1
              Editor.Text &="Dim" & Space(1) & sName(j) & 1 & Space(1) & "As" & Space(1) & _     
                                        ctrlName(j) & "=New" & Space(1) & ctrlName(j) & VbCrLf                                        
              For i=1 To arr1(j)-1 Step 2                                
                   Editor.Text &="Dim" & Space(1) & sName(j) & i+1 & Space(1) & "As" & Space(1) & _     
                                            ctrlName(j) & "=New" & Space(1) & ctrlName(j) & ":" & _
                                            "Dim" & Space(1) & sName(j) & i+2 & Space(1) & "As" & Space(1) & _     
                                            ctrlName(j) & "=New" & Space(1) & ctrlName(j) & VbCrLf
             Next
       Next              
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
End Sub
```

The following file is that of ArrayDemo.vbproj:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{BE9B3350-5541-4EB5-BD4D-F6938B472E5E}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>ArrayDemo</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>ArrayDemo</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <MyType>Custom</MyType>
    <PublishUrl>publish\</PublishUrl>
    <Install>true</Install>
    <InstallFrom>Disk</InstallFrom>
    <UpdateEnabled>false</UpdateEnabled>
    <UpdateMode>Foreground</UpdateMode>
    <UpdateInterval>7</UpdateInterval>
    <UpdateIntervalUnits>Days</UpdateIntervalUnits>
    <UpdatePeriodically>false</UpdatePeriodically>
    <UpdateRequired>false</UpdateRequired>
    <MapFileExtensions>true</MapFileExtensions>
    <ApplicationRevision>0</ApplicationRevision>
    <ApplicationVersion>1.0.0.%2a</ApplicationVersion>
    <IsWebBootstrapper>false</IsWebBootstrapper>
    <UseApplicationTrust>false</UseApplicationTrust>
    <BootstrapperEnabled>true</BootstrapperEnabled>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <DefineDebug>true</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <IncrementalBuild>true</IncrementalBuild>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DocumentationFile>ArrayDemo.xml</DocumentationFile>
    <NoWarn>41999,42016,42017,42018,42019,42020,42021,42022,42032,42036,42314</NoWarn>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>   
    <Reference Include="PresentationCore" />
    <Reference Include="PresentationFramework" /> 
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />    
    <Reference Include="System" />    
    <Reference Include="System.Xaml">    
      <RequiredTargetFramework>4.0</RequiredTargetFramework>
    </Reference>   
    <Reference Include="WindowsBase" /> 
    <Reference Include="PresentationCore" />
    <Reference Include="PresentationFramework" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ApplicationDefinition Include="ArrayDemo.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </ApplicationDefinition>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>    
    <Imports Include="System.Windows.Documents" />    
    <Import Include="System.Collections.Generic" />
    <Import Include="System.Collections" />
    <Import Include="System.ComponentModel" />                  
    <Import Include="Microsoft.VisualBasic" />
    <Import Include="Microsoft.Win32" />    
    <Import Include="System.Windows.Application" />
    <Import Include="System.IO" />
    <Import Include="System" />
    <Import Include="System.Web" />
    <Import Include="System.Windows" />    
    <Import Include="System.Windows.Controls" />    
    <Import Include="System.Windows.Threading" />    
  </ItemGroup> 
  <ItemGroup>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 %28x86 and x64%29</ProductName>
      <Install>true</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.5.SP1">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5 SP1</ProductName>
      <Install>false</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.VisualBasic.targets" />
</Project>
```

compilation code from cmd--is given below--place the project folder with ArrayDemo.xaml and ArrayDemo.vbproj in D:\ drive--and call the compilation code from cmd. Your GUI will pop out on your screen--i have reduced the viewbox size to suit smaller screen sizes. If your screen size is different then readjust viewbox dimentions suitably.