# String [] but [] in the script

Tags: c#, string, filter

I am making a **simple badword filter** for my game! The badwords = string[] (that means that i can put all the bad words, that should be blocked, in strings[] in unity one by one.**(picture one)**

The **problem** is that i want **many badwords** to be blocked and it would probably take **too much time** to put all the badwords in strings[] one by one.

**Solution:** Is it possible to somehow put all the **bad words in a script?** So that i for example can copy&paste them from a badword list?

**What I've tried:** I've tried to make the **string[] to a normal string** and then string = "badwords" then i got an error that said that the string can't be converted to an char or something like that **(picture 4)**

**I am thankful for any help! :D**

[image: This is where i put the bad words one by one]
[image: script]
[image: The script that removes the bad words from the text]

Edit: That is the new code, i'm not really sure how to make this to the string[] badwors? 
I now noticed that in the second picture, there is no [] for the "String badwords", but usually there is a [] after the string(String[] badwords;)

```
public static void FormatBadWords()
{
    string pattern = "[,]+";
    string input = "bad, toobad, crazy";
    string[] result = Regex.Split(input, pattern,
                                  RegexOptions.IgnoreCase,
                                  TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
    for (int ctr = 0; ctr < result.Length; ctr++)
    {
        Console.Write("'{0}'", result[ctr]);
        if (ctr < result.Length - 1)
            Console.Write(", ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: You should still use a `string[]`. You just need to process the string from the bad words list. What does the bad words list look like?

Comment: But *please* don't post the actual list of bad words - you'll probably then get the post closed as "rude!"

Comment: Please [post code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode), not images. And do not add irrelevant tags; `visual-studio` is for problems with the Visual Studio application, not to tell us that you are using Visual Studio. Similarly `unity3d` is for problems with the Unity package.

Comment: @Sweeper Hey! Thank you for your time! The bad words list looks like that: bad, bad, bad, etc.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126915/how-do-i-split-a-string-by-a-multi-character-delimiter-in-c) help?

Comment: @Sweeper Thank you! The only problem now is how to get the code to be "string[] badwords"  The code:  Oh, i don't know how to post the code here but i edited my main question! :D

Answer (score 0):

**You can use string.Split() and use a text file with comma-separated values:**

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Assume this as your string that needs fiter
        string myString = "These are my bad words: bad, toBad";

        //Put words in a file or simply hardcode: string badWordsCommaSeperated = "bad, toBad"
        string badWordsCommaSeperated = File.ReadAllText(@"..\..\BadWords.txt");

        //Catch the above Comma-Seperated string in string array
        string[] badWords = badWordsCommaSeperated.Split(',');

        // Loop all bad words in the array using foreach and replace myString
        foreach(string badWord in badWords)
        {
            myString = myString.Replace(badWord, "");
        }

        Console.WriteLine(myString);
        //Final Value of myString: These are my  words: ,
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You might want to [split on `", "`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245442/), not just `','`.